# Spherical error variance in OLS estimation of AR($p$)

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, least-squares, estimators

Consider the linear model $\boldsymbol y=\boldsymbol X\beta+\boldsymbol\varepsilon$. One of the assumptions for the OLS estimator is the spherical error variance assumption which states that $\operatorname E[\boldsymbol\varepsilon\boldsymbol\varepsilon'\mid\boldsymbol X]=\sigma^2I_n$.

Suppose that we want to estimate the parameters of the AR($p$) model defined by
$$
X_t=\mu+\phi_1X_{t-1}+\ldots+\phi_pX_{t-p}+\varepsilon_t
$$
by regressing $X_t$ on the constant and $X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{t-p}$. The errors $\varepsilon_t$ are assumed to be iid random variables with zero means and variances equal to $\sigma^2>0$.

> Is the spherical error variance assumption satisfied in this case?

I think that the answer is negative since in this case the matrix $\boldsymbol X$ contains $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$ is measurable with respect to the sigma algebra generated by $\boldsymbol X$. For example,
$$
\varepsilon_n=X_n-\mu-\phi_1X_{n-1}-\ldots-\phi_pX_{n-p}
$$
and all the random variables on the right hand side of the equation above are contained in the matrix $\boldsymbol X$. Hence, it follows that $\operatorname E[\boldsymbol\varepsilon\boldsymbol\varepsilon'\mid\boldsymbol X]=\boldsymbol\varepsilon\boldsymbol\varepsilon'$ and we see that the spherical error variance assumption is not satisfied. Is this correct?

Any help is much appreciated!